# Why doesn't componentDidMount method work when it’s called after the second time?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to change what a component shows depending on the URL parameter but at the same time to use the same component. When I execute my code componentDidMount is evoked for the first time, but after the second time, it doesn't work. As a result, I can't change what the component shows.

I'm using react.js.
Although I used componentDidUpdate instead of componentDidMount it caused an infinitive loop.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import Contentful from "./Contentful";
import "./Article.css";

class ArticlesWithTag extends React.Component {
  state = {
    articleFromContentful: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    const { tag } = this.props.match.params;
    //get article from contentful API
    const contentful = new Contentful();
    try {
      const article = await contentful.getArtcleWithTags(
        undefined,
        "blogPost",
        tag
      );
      this.setState({ articleFromContentful: article.items });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error");
      console.log(err);
    }
  }


  render() {
    const bodyOfArticle = this.state.articleFromContentful.map(data => {
      const returnTitle = () => {
        return data.fields.title;
      };

      const returnPublishedDate = () => {
        let date = data.fields.publishDate.substring(0, 10);
        let replacedDate = date.replace("-", "/");

        while (date !== replacedDate) {
          date = date.replace("-", "/");
          replacedDate = replacedDate.replace("-", "/");
        }
        return replacedDate;
      };

      const returnBody = () => {
        return data.fields.body;
      };

      const returnTags = () => {
        const tagList = data.fields.tags.map(data => {
          const listContent = `#${data}`;
          return <li>{listContent}</li>;
        });
        return tagList;
      };

      returnTags();
      return (
        <div className="article-container">
          <div className="article-title">{returnTitle()}</div>
          <p className="article-date">{returnPublishedDate()}</p>
          <div className="article-body">
            <ReactMarkdown source={returnBody()}></ReactMarkdown>
          </div>
          <div className="article-tags">
            <ul>{returnTags()}</ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return <div className="article-outer">{bodyOfArticle}</div>;
  }
}

export default ArticlesWithTag;
```

Comment: componentDidMount() is used to initialise functions or states. It runs when the component is mounted. So it is only the entry point. Anything you want to change should be done inside other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok **componentDidMount** is a lifecylce method that runs only when the component mounts
and **componentDidUpdate** runs everytime there's an update

You can set state in componentDidUpdate but it **must be wrapped around some condition**
In your case you can do something like this

```
 async componentDidMount() {
console.log("componentDidMount");
const { tag } = this.props.match.params;
//get article from contentful API
const contentful = new Contentful();
try {
  const article = await contentful.getArtcleWithTags(
    undefined,
    "blogPost",
    tag
  );
  this.setState({ articleFromContentful: article.items });
} catch (err) {
  console.log("error");
  console.log(err);
}
}
```

and for further updates use compnentDidUpdate  as

```
 async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
const { tag } = this.props.match.params;
//get article from contentful API
const contentful = new Contentful();
if ( tag !== prevProps.match.params ) // if props have changed
{
try {
  const article = await contentful.getArtcleWithTags(
    undefined,
    "blogPost",
    tag
  );
  this.setState({ articleFromContentful: article.items });
} catch (err) {
  console.log("error");
  console.log(err);
}
}
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @Marie glad it worked for you, if it helped you please accept my answer, cheers

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount is called only when your component is mounted.
componentDidUpdate is called when the props has changed. 
You should create a function from your componentDidMount logic and call it in componentDidUpdate only when tag has changed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally, I've fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount()` is only called when the component initially mounts onto the DOM. Re-renders caused by prop or state changes trigger `componentDidUpdate()`. As you mentioned, making state changes in this function causes infinite loops.

What you can do is use `componentDidUpdate()` and check if props have changed before deciding to update the state again. This should prevent your infinite loop situation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally, I've fixed it. Thank you so much!